# XDE.exe using > 35% CPU all of the time - is this expected behaviour? (VS Android Emulator)

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I have an Android Marshmallow device in the Visual Studio Android Emulator (April 2016 release), and it starts fine and seems to work. However, while running, the `XDE.exe` process is killing my CPU (35-40%+) while Hyper-V is only using ~8-10% max.

Is this normal and expected behavior? If not, how can I fix it?

I was able to track the high CPU usage down to the following DLL:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   XDE\10.0.10586.0\Plugins\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.XdePlugin.dll

... and the following thread that runs this method, which is a loop:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.StatusCallback.XdeDeviceStatusCallbackService.StatusCallbackThreadProc()

I do not see such high CPU usage of XDE when running the Windows 10 mobile emulator images.

Comment: Same problem here, except only 12%. But this corresponds with a single core on my PC.

Comment: Yup - seems to have started after the Visual Studio 2015 Update3 upgrade :|

Comment: Same problem here, still no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @cmeeren I didn't unforutnately.

Answer (score 1):

I answer you in order

Yes it's normal.

You have an issue in the official [Win Dev Center.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/34f25099-0c3f-482d-896f-585ed46fca89/vs-emulator-for-android?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using ILSpy and ReflexIL to add a Thread.Sleep(100) call in the StatusCallbackThreadProc() function. Then I needed to switch off strongname verification by adding to the registry the following line:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.XdePlugin,B03F5F7F11D50A3A

If there is demand for my version of the dll please let me know...